# How to create API Keys in GCP using service accont

Tags: google-cloud-platform, api-key, service-accounts

I have a service account with Owner permissions on the project (Just for testing this out)
Still I am not able to create API Keys using that service account via gcloud. It says "Permission Denied"
I am using the following commands.

```
1.
gcloud auth activate-service-account <Service-account>@<project-id>.iam.gserviceaccount.com --key-file=<key-file>.json

2.
gcloud auth list //Gives the service account name

3.
gcloud alpha services api-keys create --display-name=dummy
```

The above command works if I authenticate as a normal user with Owner permission but with service account it doesn't seems to work. Am I missing something ? Please help.

Comment: Don't forget to define the [key file path](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/activate-service-account)

Comment: Thanks Dany. I have specified it already.

Comment: Can you say more about how it's not working? Failing with an error? Hanging indefinitely? Finishing up nicely but doesn't actually create the key?

Answer (score 1):

The APIKEY Api has a strange history. Relesed in Beta about 1 years ago, and now go back to Alpha. There is no public documentation (in reality it has been removed) and if you know this API, you have found it on SO or on old tutorial.

Anyway, just to say that it's not a reliable API and if you want to automate stuff on it (with call with a service account) it's not a good idea. In addition, sometime, APIs don't allow service account call but require user credentials. It was the case previously with the quota APIs, but it has been updated recently (this summer 2020).

Eventually, Google Cloud don't recommend to use APIKEY for security reason (we can discuss this more if you want). And thus, I don't think it is in its (security and best practice) strategy to promote an API that allows APIKEY automation.

Comment: Thank you for the insight. This has helped however I wanted to know what other security mechanisms can be used to secure access to your api-gateway or lets say cloud endpoint urls?

Comment: That's a good question!! If it's user oriented application, Firebase Auth is the right solution. If it's server to server call, and the server at the initiative of the call can't generate OAuth2 credentials based on a service account key file, you can use.... API KEY!!! Yes, I know it's frustrating, because it's the only solution and you can't automate it... I already talked about this to apigateway PM, he had to send me info, but I never received input on this case...